# How can I make my custom JavaScript code work properly in AngularJS MVC?

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

As a simple example from my custom JavaScript file:

```
if(document.URL.indexOf("http://localhost/Angular/Angular_Project_01/index.html#!/myinfo") >= 0)
    {
    alert("you are viewing myinfo page");
    }
```

This will only execute if page is refreshed while in the myinfo view. The problem is this page contains forms that need to be disabled after user has entered his/her information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked well for me in this project. Not sure if it's best practice though.

```
window.addEventListener('hashchange', function() {

    if(window.location.hash == '#!/myinfo' //&& something)
        {
        console.log("Hash is #!/myinfo");

        setTimeout(function() //Avoid TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null
            { 
            //Do something
            }, 1000);
        }
});
```